# Cannot get twitter to work

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to post a image and some text to my twitter status, but all the tutorials that I have found do not work. Each and every one says "Login failed". This is getting ridiculous. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction? Please give suggestions.

PS - I have added the correct secret and key.

**EDIT**

I am using an existing app, just trying to get it to work so that I can see what a good way of implementing the functionality is. I downloaded the project from github at [this](https://github.com/khetiyachintan/Android-Twitter-Example) link.

Comment: Are you having problem with an existing twitter app, or are you trying to write one with Twitter access? If it's the latter please add some relevant code.  Without any it is unlikely anyone can show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: And for future reference, give a reason for down votes so that I can improve where I am at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code.

```
private void shareOnTwitter() {
        try{
        Intent shareIntent = findTwitterClient(); 
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "added an item to iCollect(Android)! " + strMake + " " + strModel);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Twitter app not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

public Intent findTwitterClient() {
        final String[] twitterApps = {
                // package // name - nb installs (thousands)
                "com.twitter.android", // official - 10 000
                "com.twidroid", // twidroid - 5 000
                "com.handmark.tweetcaster", // Tweecaster - 5 000
                "com.thedeck.android" }; // TweetDeck - 5 000 };
        Intent tweetIntent = new Intent();
        tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (int i = 0; i < twitterApps.length; i++) {
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
                String p = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                if (p != null && p.startsWith(twitterApps[i])) {
                    tweetIntent.setPackage(p);
                    return tweetIntent;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

It would be a problem if I don't have all the package names, but at the moment it will suffice.